# how can i tell if legacy asp code is using the webforms, mvc or webpages development model?

Tags: asp.net

I am learning some legacy asp.net code. I got [on W3 schools to get started](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/default.asp) and learned that there are 3 different development models. I'm brand new to ASP.net (but have lots of experience with winforms). How can I tell which model the code is using?

Comment: A much better place to learn is http://asp.net.

Comment: There is controversy around w3schools.com containing incorrect information.  Use caution and do your own research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the solution have a bunch of `.aspx` files?  If so, Webforms.

Does it have a bunch of `.cshtml`, `.vbhtml`, or `.aspx` files in a `views` folder, with a `controllers` and `models` folder in the solution too?  If so, MVC.

Does the project have a bunch of `.cshtml` or `.vbhtml` files scattered through multiple folders (or no folders)?  If so, WebPages.

[Here is a comparison between the 3.](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/aspnet-web-pages-%28razor%29-faq#Whats_the_difference_between_ASP.NET_Web_Pages,_ASP.NET_Web_Forms,_and_ASP.NET_MVC)

Comment: I have no idea if this answer is 100% comprehensive but it looks like a pretty good rule of thumb. :)

Comment: Yeah, there is a lot of overlap, especially between MVC and WebPages.